# output redirection produces empty file

Tags: c, linux, bash

So this is probably a stupid question, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I am running a program that produces output when called like `./ar`. The output looks like:

```
-0.00781 0.02344 0.98828                                                        
-0.01172 0.02734 0.98828                                                        
-0.01562 0.02344 0.98047                                                        
-0.00781 0.02344 1.00000                                                        
-0.00391 0.02344 0.98438
```

A new line of output is written every second.

When I call the code like this `./ar > log` and kill the program using `ctrl-c` after a few seconds, the file `log` is empty.

I am running this code on an embedded system. The system has a writeable partition which is the partition that I am running in, and I have write access as I am logged in as root.

Comment: When you redirect, the output is block-buffered, not line-buffered. If you hit Ctrl-C before a block is full, nothing gets written to the file. You can use `fflush(stdout)` to make it write to the file immediately.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem, I had to run this line prior to every printf statement.

Comment: Doing it after the `printf` is more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are looking at standard output in you call ./ar? It might be standard error.
So, try ./ar >log 2>err to have 2 files, one for stdout and one for stderr.

Or use ./ar 2>&1 >log to get one file for both streams.